# Worflow service (WF4) - Forms authentication not working

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

I have a Workflow Service serving XAMLX workflows.

I want to enable Forms Authentication on it so I can authenticate to it and have access to the Context.Current.Identity.Name to get the name of the user.

However, when I activate forms authentication in the Web.config, as I do normally in ASP.NET sites or WCF services, it doesn't work. It looks like it is totally ignored by the host and I do not get redirected to a login page.

Other details : it is deployed in IIS7 and we use a wsHttpBinding

Any ideas on the causes of the problem?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

The wsHttpBinding doesn't use forms auth but WS security. And realy what would the use be for a redirect to the logon page? There is some code calling a WS service not a browser that can display the login page to an end user.

Comment: You are right about the login page, I was just trying to illustrate that the Forms auth was ignored. Thanks for your feedback, I'll try something else than wsHttpBinding and will let you know